# Rails app not being pushed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My rails app will not push to deploy. I have done research a scoured the web to find a solution, but can not find anything. :( Heroku seems to be acting up. I haven't done anything to my gem file or ruby versions etc.

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.5 


Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.3.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

## Full Log

```
 2017-02-16T07:56:20.936637+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `block in start'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936638+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:33:in `start'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936638+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:164:in `start'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936639+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936640+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936641+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936642+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936643+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936644+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936645+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936645+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936647+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936648+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936799+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 07:56:20] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2017-02-16T07:56:20.936882+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 07:56:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2017-02-16T07:56:20.965671+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-02-16T08:42:07.305645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-02-16T08:42:07.305968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-02-16T08:42:10.098276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 47049 -e production`
2017-02-16T08:42:14.287145+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-02-16T08:42:14.013327+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 08:42:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2017-02-16T08:42:14.013352+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 08:42:14] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
2017-02-16T08:42:14.013592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 08:42:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=47049
2017-02-16T08:42:16.032374+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:47049
2017-02-16T08:42:16.032355+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2017-02-16T08:42:16.032375+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-02-16T08:42:16.032376+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2017-02-16T08:42:22.876239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-eddd60da1a5ee09fa9e268557cb34840bd8c4969e2b61604cebae47699c0a3a3.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=da49fb68-2890-41ba-b15c-2d5c18413c16 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=41293
2017-02-16T08:42:22.646986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=f3e57e90-bb48-4787-a955-54d3ffaa44ed fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7018ms status=200 bytes=4971
2017-02-16T08:42:22.957280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=45d33fbf-17a9-4c28-a11a-4bbf4f2ad996 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T08:42:22.935551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1bbcb429975b9560cc327a66f838267356775c65a1b8a80b0ba21dc85dd4bb69.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=ce2c2fc8-ab9c-4793-819e-a18e452679ba fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=70467
2017-02-16T08:42:22.958710+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/cmrf-logo-c8730395cd2ca2797d05180e3fa681780bf70ba12d130d470faf297c1cb3b3f1.png" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=3300c430-cc27-420a-9a66-4bf6f1002de3 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=10353
2017-02-16T08:42:22.942254+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=986eda60-4a5f-4470-b59b-0d091f899f92 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T08:42:22.968662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=cde341bd-2794-4f26-8a7f-2b256b6b6176 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T08:42:36.225328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/crum.jpeg" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=86436e62-e19c-4d9d-bcd9-6721c73ef00f fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=4049
2017-02-16T08:42:36.720977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/crum.jpeg" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=017dbe82-6054-4cf9-84cb-76bc3b6eebd3 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=343
2017-02-16T08:42:58.408361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=dfcfc449-ee08-475f-9ee0-98f17bad0e70 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T08:42:58.204452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=00426e62-b6ab-4002-9474-48f3ed2d6f6b fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=4971
2017-02-16T08:42:58.355543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=365d28b1-da51-412f-ae98-f85795f8df4e fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T08:42:58.410522+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=eac1f48f-508d-47d3-b2a7-14e3ab0cd542 fwd="37.228.245.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T09:19:25.326892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-02-16T09:19:25.327541+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-02-16T09:19:25.958118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-02-16T09:19:26.144833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967779+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 09:19:25] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967789+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `select'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967792+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `block in start'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967793+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:33:in `start'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967793+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:164:in `start'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967794+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967795+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967795+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967796+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967797+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967798+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967798+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967799+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967800+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967800+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967875+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 09:19:25] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2017-02-16T09:19:25.967920+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 09:19:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2017-02-16T09:19:25.984297+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-02-16T22:48:10.763483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-02-16T22:48:10.763837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-02-16T22:48:13.849804+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 26006 -e production`
2017-02-16T22:48:18.837654+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 22:48:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2017-02-16T22:48:18.837710+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 22:48:18] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
2017-02-16T22:48:18.837895+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-16 22:48:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=26006
2017-02-16T22:48:19.162640+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-02-16T22:48:20.758038+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2017-02-16T22:48:20.758074+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:26006
2017-02-16T22:48:20.758076+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2017-02-16T22:48:20.758075+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-02-16T22:48:28.070252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=f8db71e3-291a-42c8-8d9d-f59cd793f1fd fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7810ms status=200 bytes=4971
2017-02-16T22:48:28.062332+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=54d3fbad-a091-4a4e-b98c-7eb32857b0bb fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7958ms status=200 bytes=4971
2017-02-16T22:48:28.243981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-eddd60da1a5ee09fa9e268557cb34840bd8c4969e2b61604cebae47699c0a3a3.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=fce151b6-71a2-4812-8180-f6f89fab1b0b fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=41293
2017-02-16T22:48:28.644743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1bbcb429975b9560cc327a66f838267356775c65a1b8a80b0ba21dc85dd4bb69.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=90259c7a-d679-4add-8d0c-3934391212e9 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2017-02-16T22:48:28.997200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=e139f5b1-d001-457b-b2f6-715c861ce869 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T22:48:28.649015+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=e8c6d4ff-7506-4bcb-a071-6af2a5462cc8 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T22:48:28.829022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=1166bcbb-c0b9-4c58-b043-bbc3b79fc223 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T22:48:29.186936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/cmrf-logo-c8730395cd2ca2797d05180e3fa681780bf70ba12d130d470faf297c1cb3b3f1.png" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=431ec8ff-6dc9-465f-86c2-b295ed1a9528 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=10353
2017-02-16T22:48:29.174197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=d03eaa7f-f4f7-4c5b-9546-165575de5d89 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T22:48:29.404749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=fba18bb4-719f-4175-90af-9a70a77f85ac fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T22:48:29.586183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=52096f14-100f-4f9e-898e-b19716567096 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T22:48:31.080439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/crum-2a7c889ad8ade7ab053966af53f5ac776e973e29a2d094f970ebfa91e4cc6c04.jpg" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=5ae87ba2-df07-4003-982d-2ecc07d3e044 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=3885
2017-02-16T23:07:56.909999+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-16T23:11:40.847919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=3dcba586-f777-45f8-a065-b5b245a182b1 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=47ms status=200 bytes=4971
2017-02-16T23:11:41.533475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=067c4f5d-94d0-4035-9f42-8e778fa3c338 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T23:11:41.519325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-eddd60da1a5ee09fa9e268557cb34840bd8c4969e2b61604cebae47699c0a3a3.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=834bf7f0-3cc0-41c5-82bd-122cc77b29df fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=41293
2017-02-16T23:11:43.022883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=26c38eb6-1b14-4fdc-a8a9-adcbc39e16ba fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T23:11:43.243931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=ebe7fe49-7383-44ce-bbff-331d694ef93c fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T23:11:43.288095+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/cmrf-logo-c8730395cd2ca2797d05180e3fa681780bf70ba12d130d470faf297c1cb3b3f1.png" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=f2df56c7-0bee-45e5-97fa-a0702e58132d fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=10353
2017-02-16T23:11:43.407419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/bootstrap.min.css" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=3e64c34a-11a8-4d9e-82e8-9eae2eb354be fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T23:11:43.684210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/jquery.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=074fc9fe-e4c7-41ab-9ef2-9511de24cc92 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T23:11:43.848125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/bootstrap.min.js" host=murmuring-sands-51562.herokuapp.com request_id=ab871d1a-0b4f-47f2-8241-a1ea566d8b99 fwd="208.87.57.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1829
2017-02-16T23:13:24.918367+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-16T23:19:28.577889+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-16T23:20:26.002471+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-16T23:26:48.453351+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-16T23:27:41.288116+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-02-16T23:31:54.424907+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
```

Comment: I think
#recommended by Heroku for hosting
ruby "2.3.1"
You have an unexpected end of file error. Does it have to do with how you use the webrick server? Think about using puma maybe: However, did you configure the webrick server manually and that is why it crashes?

Comment: No this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `curl -L` run `curl -L -w ""`. This set the `--write-out` option to an empty string and prevents cURL from appending any characters to the end of the output. So, provided the internet connection of your machine is fine, this should eliminate the `gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file` error.

Also, the `-o -` can be omitted as that is already the default behaviour.